# Homotopy Equivalence on the filtration of a CW-Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I am new to algebraic topology and I need some help. I am having some difficulties to prove the following statement, which I did not find in different standard textbooks:

Let X, Y be a CW-Complexes such that X has a filtration into subcomplexes:

[image]

and similarly for Y.  Let f: X --> Y be a continuous map such that for each n the restriction f: Xn --> Yn is an homotopy equivalence. Then f is an homotopy equivalence.

Could you please help me or tell me where I could find this?

Comment: Note that $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ has the homotopy extension property, same for $Y_n \subset Y_{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok this is a good advice. So here is a try : I define the homotopy inverse of f piecewise, by taking each homotopy inverse g: Yn --> Xn. Then I extend the homotopy between (gf) and the identity on Xn to Xn+1 for all n. Then I extend the homotopy from any Xn to X. Since restricted on each Xn, this is an homotopy between (gf) and the identity on Xn, it is an homotopy between (gf) and the identity on X. Does this work?

Comment: Almost. I think you need to use the HEP to define a global map $g':Y\to X$ that restricts to maps $g'_n: Y_n \to X_n$ that are all homotopic to the homotopy inverses $g_n: Y_n \to X_n$. It is not clear that the respective homotopy inverses fit together to form a map $Y\to X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to have the following result, which is a version of 7.4.2 and its Addendum of  [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html). This result was found in the 1960s by generalising the well known result that if $f:Y  \to Z$ is a homotopy equivalence, then $f$ induces an isomorphism of homotopy groups: the issue is that homotopy groups are defined only for pointed spaces, but we do not assume $f$ is a homotopy equivalence of pointed spaces.

Let $(f,g):(Y,A) \to (Z,B)$ be a map of pairs of spaces such that the inclusions $i:A\to Y$, $j:B \to Z$ are cofibrations, and $f:Y \to Z, g:A \to B$ are homotopy equivalences with homotopy inverse $g': B \to A$ of $g$ and homotopies $H: g'g\simeq 1$, $K:gg' \simeq 1$. Then $f$ has a homotopy inverse $f':Z \to Y$ extending $g'$, and there are  homotopies $H':ff' \simeq 1$, $K':f'f \simeq 1$ which extend respectively the homotopies $H$ and 
$$ K+ gHg' - gg'K. $$

It does not seem possible to simplify the curious "conjugate" homotopy given above. For example, one might expect that you can choose a homotopy $K'$ extending $K$, but I do not have a counterexample. (There is such a counterexample  in the dual case, for fibrations, for which a relevant discussion is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208413/pull-back-of-a-fibration-along-a-homotopy-equivalence-and-homotopy-classes-of-se).)

Going back to the question, you can use the above to work by induction to get maps and homotopies which fit together.